# How can I change the colour of the selection box and handles in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't see any selections on a white page as all paths, boxes and handles are now white!
If a drag them off the page I can see they are there against the grey background.

I've reset all my Preferences but it has made no difference.

Any ideas on how to select blue again?

(Illustrator 2020)

Comment: What color is the layer you're using?

Comment: White!  I've set it to blue and everything is back. Simple when you know how.

Comment: Many thanks Chris!

Answer (score 2):

Double click the Layer thumbnail in the **Layers panel** and choose a new highlight color.